# dismiss rootViewController on button tap

Tags: objective-c, viewcontroller, dismiss, rootviewcontroller

I have a `viewController` instantiated by storyboard on application launch which is a part of hybrid app. On top of that I have presented one more view controller. Now While dismissing the `presentedViewController` I want to dismiss the `rootViewController` as well so as to show the hybrid app screen. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please share your code how you present your rootviewcontroller and otherViewController

Comment: [_arViewController setOnlyShowItemsWithinRadarRange:YES];

    [self presentViewController:_arViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }


This is how I have presented the second ViewController. First one is the storyboard's Default ViewController

Comment: It will dismiss the presented ViewController. I want to dismiss/Remove the rootViewController as well so that hybrid app screen should display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{


 // after your second view controller dismissed.
 // set your new view controller as a root of window.
 // You need to set navigation controller and set any root view controller for that navigation controller in storyboard.
// also don't forget to set identifier of your navigation controller.


   UINavigationController* rootController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:kStoryboardName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"controllerIdentifier"];

   UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
   window.rootViewController = rootController; 

  // this will set your new navigation controller with root view on UIWindow.

}];
```

Comment: "property window not found on presented ViewController" error

Comment: I want to remove the root ViewController only instead of changing it to some other controllers. Then only the hybrid app screen can takes taps on it. Right now native applications screen remains on top of hybrid app screen as a result hybrid application is not accepting any taps on it

Answer (score 1):

OK, I don't know anything about Worklight. Or what a hybrid app is. So this may not make sense. But here's a strictly iOS answer to your question.

It doesn't really make sense to dismiss the root view controller without replacing it with another view controller. If you do, you would leave your app with no way to interact with it (except maybe shaking the phone?).

So there isn't a way to dismiss it as you can with child view controllers. But you can just remove it.

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[keyWindow.rootViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
keyWindow.rootViewController = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[viewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```